# Best way to select a String within a String

Tags: c#, string

I have this string;

```
<div class="flip-entry-title">System~1584~CommandName-e.dat</div></div><div class="flip-entry-last-modified"><div>18 Αυγ</div></div></div><div class="flip-entry" id="entry-0B4jdixTeku1LMlpNdEtOSmhxWWM"
```

What is the best efficient way to pick `System~560~Charcreategrp.dat` and `entry-0B4jdixTeku1LMlpNdEtOSmhxWWM`

I know I can use `Regex.split` and `substring(x, y)` but I want to know if theres a class or a method in C# that will do this job for me.

Comment: If it's always going to be HTML then HTMLAgilityPack may be of interest - otherwise Regex

Comment: try this regex http://regex101.com/r/xF9iP4/1

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Unfortunately, solved with Regex + substring, thanks everyone for your help

Comment: @user3789587 [You can't parse XML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1808494)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are not good for your case take a look at these:

- [String-Extension-Collection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31050/String-Extension-Collection-for-C)
- [C#-String-Methods](http://extensionmethod.net/csharp/string)

Can you explain why Regex and substring() are no option?

***Update:***
Ok, I understand. As you know working with *String* may be slow - you can try *StringBuilder* (way faster), but 2-400 operations can be high number, when you append/join or split/search.

> split and substring make the code unreadable and too complex,

Even if you think so - you can always create proper comments...self-documenting/explanatory  code is very helpful and is one of the **best-practices**.

Comment: split and substring make the code unreadable and too complex, since i have an unknown number of strings 200 - 400 that I have to process

Comment: Also, I get those HTML string from the web, their order/contents may change at any time so I need a more generic aproach

Answer (score 1):

If it is always XML (or HTML) you could parse it

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(myStr);
```

And then use XPath or Linq to fetch what you need from `doc`.